# function "animate" starts after a long time

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a problem, my problem is that the function "animate" jquery takes to run. My project requires that the header is pump out when scrolldown, because the "height" + "transition" of css do very abrupt, I decided to use the function "animate" jquery, the problem is that it shrinks everything and my "input" shrinks after a long time

```
$('document').ready(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function()
    {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 19) {
            $(".ui-autocomplete-input").animate({"height": "19px"},"fast");
            $('#header-container').addClass("scale-header");
            $('.top_menu').slideUp();



        }
        else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 19) {
            $(".ui-autocomplete-input").animate({"height": "34px"},"fast");
            $('#header-container').removeClass("scale-header");
            $('.top_menu').slideDown();

        }


    });

});
```

*I need a "slideUp" and "slideDown" 18px to 32px*

thanks!

Comment: could you make a js fiddle?

Comment: Takes what to run? Long time? Short time? Please clarify the title.

Comment: takes to run a long time, the entire header of reduced and after a few seconds reduces the input

Comment: I need a "slideUp" and "slideDown" 18px to 32px